# Reverse hex to rgba() to get necessary opacity for overlaying colors

Tags: css, colors, rgb, rgba

Let's say I have two similar hexadecimal colors: `#7a82f1` and `#a1a6f4` with respective `rgb(122, 130, 241)` and `rgb(161, 166, 244)`. Let's assume the second color can be achieved in a child element by setting the CSS to add some white (with a variable opacity) on top of the parent color (the first color).

Is there any way to "reverse rgba" to find the opacity on white (or black) that can be applied on one color to get the other? For example:

```
.parent {         
    background: #7a82f1;     
    .child {
         background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); //This is #a1a6f4! however, how do I find out 0.3 without knowing it?
    }
}
```

The purpose is to be able to work off png/jpeg designs rather than dealing with the intricacies of PSD files (or having to hand off your own).

Comment: Any solutions on this? I know it's been awhile but I can't find another example that parallels my needs as much as this one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that

1. Background is black.
2. The A channel is linear (0-255), so 0=black (background) and 255=foreground
3. The grayscale is linear (0-255), so 0=black and 255=white

Then gray 35 at opacity 255 is the same as gray 52 at opacity 255*35/52 = 171.

But all these assumptions are dubious. In games programming using float values for colours and transparency and with control over the gamma curve this is all much easier. In CSS, not so much.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's all a little confusing. Can you simplify? I'm looking to get from one color to another not to both colors from a black background. My purpose of using rgba is to make color themes extremely manageable by setting few base colors and letting nested styles calculate their own shades. Setting a black background and simply using rgba all over in the same way as hex sort of defeats the purpose. Furthermore the A channel in CSS rgba() ranges from 0.0-1.0 not 0-255. Please clarify.

Comment: To clarify on my end, I meant using a white or black grayscale on top of the base color ( `rgba(255,255,255, xx)` ), but I need to find out the 0.0-1.0 alpha value from the hexes.

Comment: To clarify even more that's assuming the colors are indeed related by this opacity relationship by the original designer, but lets say I only have the hexes. obv you cant go from red to blue by adding white

Comment: Can you please edit your original question to explain more specifically what you are trying to do. You might include sample CSS code to show where you want to use it. Then you might get the answer you are looking for. And you might fix the spelling of 'hexadecimal'.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I edit the original question